# Display the background image as tiles at Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, background-image

I am using Xamarin.Forms to develop an application for Android.
I am using the Xamarin.
I want to display the background as tiles.
I have prepared an image of 100x100 pixels.
\Android\MyApp\MyApp.Android\Resources\drawable\background.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ? >
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    x:DataType="viewmodels:LoginViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.LoginPage"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    BackgroundImage="background.jpg"
>
```

This way, the background.jpg will be enlarged and displayed.
I want to display it repeatedly in tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can display it repeatedly in tiles through below steps.
1.Create a drawable xml file on your Android project:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <bitmap  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
             android:tileMode="repeat"
             android:src="@drawable/clock" >
    </bitmap>
2.After that create below two effect classes on your shared project:
    //base class
    namespace AppTiles
{
    public class BaseEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public const string EffectNamespace = "AppTiles";

        public BaseEffect(String effectId) : base($"{EffectNamespace}. 
 {effectId}")
        {
        }
    }
}
//effect class
    namespace AppTiles
{
    public class CoverEffect : BaseEffect
    {
        public CoverEffect() : base(nameof(CoverEffect))
        {
        }
    }
}
3.Create a effect class in your Android project
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("AppTiles") ]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(AppTiles.Droid.CoverEffect), 
nameof(CoverEffect))]


namespace AppTiles.Droid
{
    public class CoverEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            UpdateBackground();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }

        private void UpdateBackground()
        {
            Android.Views.View mView = Container as Android.Views.View;

            if (mView != null)
            {
                mView.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(mView.Context, Resource.Drawable.XMLFile1);
            }
        }
    }
}
4.Add below xmal in shared main page code behind:
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">

        <StackLayout.Effects>
            <effects:CoverEffect/>
        </StackLayout.Effects>

    </StackLayout>

Below is the screenshot:
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the steps.
However, it did not work as expected.
I couldn't get the tiling to work, and it stayed in the enlarged view.
If you could give me a complete project on GitHub, I would appreciate it.
I will report the steps I took tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your response!Could you please help confirm if the size of the image is 100*100 on your side cause mine is 96*96 and it gets the tiling to work.Also,due to some restrictions on my side,could you please provide your project on Github so I can check your code?Thanks!

Comment: 1.Create a drawable xml file on your Android project:
 I created
MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Android\Resources\drawable\drawable.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <bitmap  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
             android:tileMode="repeat"
             android:src="@drawable/background" >
    </bitmap>

Comment: Sorry.I mean you need provide the Github project link.

Comment: 2.After that create below two effect classes on your shared project:
I cerated 
MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\Views\BaseEffect.cs

    //base class
    namespace MyApp.Views
{
    public class BaseEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public const string EffectNamespace = "MyApp";

        public BaseEffect(String effectId) : base($"{EffectNamespace}. 
 {effectId}")
        {
        }
    }
}

Comment: Sorry about that. The application I'm working on is sensitive and not yet public, so I haven't posted the source code on GitHub. I can cut down the content and publish it, but it will take some time.

Comment: MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Android\Resources\drawable\background.png
24*22 pixcels

Comment: //effect class
MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\Views\CoverEffect.cs
    namespace MyApp
{
    public class CoverEffect : BaseEffect
    {
        public CoverEffect() : base(nameof(CoverEffect))
        {
        }
    }
}

Comment: 3.Create a effect class in your Android project
MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.Android\CoverEffect.cs

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyApp") ]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(MyApp.Droid.CoverEffect), 
nameof(CoverEffect))]

Comment: namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class CoverEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            UpdateBackground();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }

        private void UpdateBackground()
        {
            Android.Views.View mView = Container as Android.Views.View;

            if (mView != null)
            {
                mView.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(mView.Context, Resource.Drawable.background);//<--Is it OK?
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: 4.Add below xmal in shared main page code behind:
<ContentPage 
 xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
>
    <ContentPage.Content>
  <Grid>
   <Grid.Effects>
    <effects:CoverEffect/>
   </Grid.Effects>

Comment: Hi Kao,Thanks for your response!I tested the code you provided on my side.It did worked as expected!However,there are a few things that you need confirm.

Comment: 1.Can U set a breakpoint at UpdateBackground() in CoverEffect class in Android project to make sure it gets there? 2.For this line of code [assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(AppTiles.Droid.CoverEffect), nameof(CoverEffect))] in CoverEffect class in Android project,make sure the AppTiles.Droid.CoverEffect point to current class and the latter nameof(CoverEffect))] points to the Cover class in shared project.Hope it works!

Comment: Good evening, Alex.
I've created a project and published it on GitHub.
The URL is as follows
https://github.com/misakikaoru/SG2022
Here(Screenshot_20220210-211913.png) is the screenshot as I prepared it
Android/Resources/drawable/carbon_fibre.png
I would like to tile this image, but it has been enlarged to show the image.

Comment: 1.Can you set a breakpoint at UpdateBackground() in CoverEffect class in Android project to make sure it gets there?
->Yes I can set a breakpoint atUpdateBackground() in CoverEffect class and  make sure it gets .

Comment: 2.For this line of code [assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(AppTiles.Droid.CoverEffect), nameof(CoverEffect))] in CoverEffect class in Android project.
->No I can't set breakpoint.

Comment: make sure the AppTiles.Droid.CoverEffect point to current class and the latter nameof(CoverEffect))] points to the Cover class in shared project.Hope it works! 
->Do you mean [assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(MyApp.Droid.CoverEffect), nameof(MyApp.Views.CoverEffect))] ?

Comment: I have checked your project and  found out the root cause,you only need to change this line of code  mView.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(mView.Context, Resource.Drawable.carbon_fibre);  to  mView.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(mView.Context, Resource.Drawable.drawable);

Comment: Thanks, Alex!!!! It works perfect!!!!

Comment: Good job!You are welcome!